# Cannot add networked printer to 2008 Server. Error 0x00000216

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-7, drivers

The printer is a Zebra LP 2844-z. The machine with the printer connected to it is a Windows 7 64bit. Both x86 and x64 drivers are installed. I'm trying to connect it to a Windows 2008 32bit server and I keep getting.

Windows cannot connect to the printer. Operation could not be completed (error 0x00000216).

Any ideas?

Comment: See my answer [here](http://serverfault.com/questions/505142/what-permissions-could-a-printer-driver-require/508448#508448) for general suggestions when troubleshooting print drivers.

Answer (score 1):

The work around was to:

1. Create a local port named `\\pcname\sharename`
2. Then add the printer using that port.

Comment: Glad you resolved this. Please be sure to [mark your answer accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) when you are able.